# Can I lock the resource using the resource itself as monitor?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, mutual-exclusion

I have a multithread running context. I want one resource (let's say Object r) to be mutual exclusive. Can I use the resource itself as its monitor object?

e.g.

```
    lock(r)
    {
        // do something...
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `r` stays the same object throughout - for example, `r` is a `List` that you're adding items to from several threads:

```
lock (r)
{
    r.Add("Hello world");
}
```

then this is fine - it doesn't cause any issues, and you can read it as you're specifically "locking `r`". (Just make sure you put a similar `lock` around any *other* code that's using `r` too.)

However, if `r` is being switched for another object inside the `lock`:

```
lock (r)
{
    r = new List<string>();
}
```

this *isn't* a good idea, because you could end up with two threads running the `lock` against two different versions of `r`. In this case, you should create an unchanging `object` specifically to lock against - you're more "locking the *code block*" than "locking `r`".